# check if a returned document of the mongoDB has a specific property

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

With Mongoose I have the user account using his/her phone like this:

```
const account = await db.Account.findOne({ phone: req.body.phone }) :
```

Then I want to check if there is a property named `verified` in the `account` so I used these two and both return errors:

`account.verified` and `account.hasOwnProperty('verified')`

Note that there is **no** property as `verified` in the `account` and I expect to get `undefined` or something like `null` that can be used to check for existence of the verified property!

How can I check if there is such a property?

Comment: "Both return errors" - what errors?

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide a complete sample I can't tell, but I believe you should use a callback. Like so:

```
const account = await db.Account.findOne({ phone: req.body.phone }, function(err, account) {
    console.log(account.hasOwnProperty('verified');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For this specific situation, I suggest that you change the model of `Account` to have `null` or `false` as a default value for `isVerfied` property. Example:

```
{ ...,
  isVerfied: {
    type: boolean,
    default: false
  }
}
```

Now, the property will exist so you won't have errors when trying to access it. Also, its value will be falsy so you can always check `if (account.isVerified)`.
I feel this is one of the downfalls of JavaScript being a loosely typed language, falling on errors we could avoid if we had strong typing.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check field existence using destructuring like this:

```js
const { verified } = await db.Account.findOne({ phone: req.body.phone });

if(verified) ....
else ......
```